# Is it possible to make mksh use the tilde (~) for home in the PS1?

Tags: linux, prompt, mksh

for example, instead of displaying `user@hostname:/home/user` in the prompt as per the example in the manpage, could one make mksh display `user@hostname:~` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `"\$PWD"` from the manpage with `'${PWD/#"$HOME"/\~}'`. This will replace `$HOME` with `~` if it appears at the beginning of `$PWD`. eg:

```
PS1='${USER:=$(id -un)}'"@${HOSTNAME:=$(hostname -s)}:"'${PWD/#"$HOME"/\~} '
```

Comment: I changed mine to this: ```PS1='[${USER:=$(id -un)}'"@${HOSTNAME:=$(hostname)} \${PWD/#'$HOME'/\~}]$(if (( USER_ID )); then print \$; else print \#; fi) "
``` so it look like this ```[user@hostname ~]$ ``` thanks!

Comment: See also the default `PS1` shipped in `dot.mkshrc`, which does that *and* length-limits the PWD additionally.